# Request parameter in Windows Mobile for REST API's

Tags: c#, rest, .net-3.5, windows-ce, url-parameters

I have one Windows Handheld device application on .Net framework 3.5 which has the requirement of accessing a REST API. The REST API gives me JSON output which I am going to process later. I have the following code for that:-

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest;
        string result = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
        }
```

The url variable is holding the url for the API with some query parameters in it.
For Example "http://www.something.com/Login?id=test&pwd=test".

Now my problem is I dont want to use the query string parameters rather I want to use Request parameters because the above approach does not work every time perfectly. Some times I get an "Unauthorized" error. And also I have one tokenId which I need to send everytime I am calling the API and the token Id is in base64 format.

Can anyone please help me how can I use the Request Parameter feature to send the parameter values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `Headers` property of your request object.

```
webRequest.Headers.Add("id", "test");
webRequest.Headers.Add("pwd", "test");
webRequest.Headers.Add("token", myToken);
```